# In VirtualBox, is there a way to open VM settings window from command line?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I'm writing an alternative UI for VirtualBox using [rofi](https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi). I can already select VMs and perform some basic actions; however, for fine-tuning settings, I still have to open the `VirtualBox` Qt GUI and find the machine there. Is there a way to somehow open the settings window for a given VM from shell (i. e. some switch for `VBoxManage` or `VirtualBox` commands)?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly but you can effectively change almost anything by calling a command line utility called VBoxManage. It is usually found in:

```
/usr/bin/VBoxManage
```

(This may vary by distrubition but this is where it is located in OpenSUSE)

This tool allows you to configure nearly every aspect of the VM, including many settings which are not available in the VirtualBox GUI. In particular, I use it to display resolution to exact dimensions which are even not present in the guest operating system. For this I call the `setvideomodehint` subcommand with resolution and color bit-depth as parameter like this:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <VMNAME> setvideomodehint 3200 1800 32
```

(Substitute `<VMNAME>` for the name of the VM you are changing)

The full documentation for the command is available [online here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html). Look for the `modifyvm` subcommand that should be very relevant to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! It's certainly an option, but I'm trying to launch the builtin settings GUI, not reimplement it from scratch :)

Comment: AFAIK, it is nit possible since the settings is part of the GUI you are trying to replace. You wold have to launch the GUI offscreen somewhow, manipulate it to open the settings panel and move that on-screen. Programmatically, this could be done (not easily) but I don't think from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

No; the VirtualBox settings window will be opened only by launchig the VirtualBox gui.